# Why would the DIR command not be working for the documents folder in CMD?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, documents, dir

Why would it be that I can't list the contents of the documents directory, but it works for every other folder. It is behaving like I accessed the special folder "My Documents", but I didn't. 
The output is:

```
Volume in drive C has no label.

Volume Serial Number is xxxxx.

Directory of C:\Users\name\Documents

[Date] [Time] <DIR>

[Date] [Time] <DIR>

0 Files(s) 0 bytes

2 Dir(s) 38,917,156,864 bytes free
```

Comment: What are you looking at to compare with the results you're getting from the command prompt?

Comment: What command line did you type that provided the described output?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe because it's a library. What you see in the 'My Documents' or 'Documents' library when you open File Explorer (Windows Explorer) is not necessarily in the %userprofile%\Documents Folder.